# bitsadmin not working when started via tfs buildagent

Tags: powershell, tfs, download, msbuild, bit

I'm new to scripting, and I have a problem I can't figure out.

I'm writing a powershell script which is supposed to download some installation files. (exe, msi, zip)

It will be started from an msbuild project, executed by a buildagent in tfs. The problem is, it wont start the downloads. I used the following command:

```
bitsadmin /transfer nodetest /download /dynamic /priority FOREGROUND "https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.15.5/node-v14.15.5-x64.msi" "C:\temp\buildPrerequisites\nodejstest.msi"
```

When I connect to the buildagent and use the command from a powershell window, it will work as intended. I also made sure, that the script gets executed from the msbuild file properly.The builduser has administrative privileges.

Has anyone an idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer? Please let me if it helped you to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

I added below to my .csproj file and build with msbuild task in my pipeline. It worked fine for me.

```
<Target Name="download" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
   <Exec Command="C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted -command &quot;&amp; { bitsadmin /transfer nodetest /download /dynamic /priority FOREGROUND https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.15.5/node-v14.15.5-x64.msi C:\temp\buildPrerequisites\nodejstest.msi } &quot;" LogStandardErrorAsError="true" ContinueOnError="false" />
</Target>
```

Above target `download` will be executed automatically when you build your project. For it is added `BeforeTargets` dependency to target `BeforeBuild`,

If you found the target is not executed when you check the build log. It is probably because you did not set the dependency target for `download` target. Like below:

```
<Target Name="download" >
 ..
</Target>
```

Then you need to make sure the msbuild task is correctly configured to run the `download` target

```
- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build'
  inputs:
    solution: **/myProject.csproj
    msbuildArguments: /t:download
```

Update:

You can also use `Invoke-WebRequest`. See below:

```
<Exec Command="C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted -command &quot;&amp; { Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.15.5/node-v14.15.5-x64.msi -OutFile C:\test\buildPrerequisites\nodejstest.msi } &quot;" LogStandardErrorAsError="true" ContinueOnError="false" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sadly, this doesnt work for me. The script including the bitsadmin command is executed, which i tested by letting it create dummy textfiles. Those get created. The logs tell me the following:
"The term 'C:\Windows\system32\bitsadmin.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again"
The path is correct. I also tried it without the fullpath and also made sure the system environment variables are set correctly

Comment: @Jensson That's weird. Could you try using `Invoke-WebRequest` instead. See above update

Comment: I found the error causing problem. msbuild was run as 32bit process, while a 32bit shell isnt capable of using bitsadmin. The shell was run in 32bit albeit having the fullpath to the 64 bit exe.